# reshape image error

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

```
im=Image.open("/Users/shalinsavalia/Desktop/CNN_Numbers/Number_7.jpg")
im
im=im.resize((28, 28), Image.ANTIALIAS) # resize the image
im = np.array(im)                       # convert to an array
print(im)
im2=im/np.max(im).astype(float)         # normalise input
test_image1=np.reshape(im2, [1,784])    # reshape it to our input placeholder shape

pred=(sess.run(y_predicted,
               feed_dict={
                   x:test_image1
               }))
predicted_class=np.argmax(pred)
print "Predicted class : {}" .format(predicted_class)
```

Error in result is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./CNN_Numbers.py", line 238, in <module>
    test_image1=np.reshape(im2, [1,784]) # reshape it to our input placeholder shape
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 257, in reshape
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 52, in _wrapfunc
    return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3136 into shape (1,784)
```

Comment: Is `im` s 2D array? If it is not, you cannot reshape it to a 2D array without adding another dimension first.

Comment: yes im is 2d array image having dimension of 256*256

Comment: But then the total image size does not match: 256 x 256 != 1 x 784. Resize the image before reshaping.

Comment: m=im.resize((28, 28), Image.ANTIALIAS) here i am trying to change the dimension of image by 28*28 i think. could you please share me the solution i am confused in this part.

Comment: You may want to check the dimensions of `im2` before reshaping it.

Comment: im2=[[[0.         0.         0.         1.        ]
  [0.         0.         0.         1.        ]
  [0.         0.         0.         1.        ]
  ...
  [0.00392157 0.00392157 0.00392157 1.        ]
  [0.         0.         0.         1.        ]
  [0.11764706 0.11764706 0.11764706 1.        ]]

Comment: im=[[[  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  ...
  [  1   1   1 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [ 30  30  30 255]]

Comment: this is how my dimension of im2 and im. something is wrong with or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your image has 3+1 color channels.  You need to reshape to [784, 4].

Comment: thank you, that works for me. I really appreciate your time.